# Blur all elements except one hovered

Tags: html, css

I have a project (a site) to make for tomorrow and I would like to add a little style but I can't seem to blur all the elements of a div except the one I'm flying over: /

Here is my code:

```css
.projetsdiv
{
    height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    align-items: center;
}
 
.isn, .tpe, .ppp
{
    width: 25%;
    align-items: center;
}
 
.isn:hover, .tpe:hover, .ppp:hover
{
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
 
#ppp-dl:hover, #ppp-pdf:hover, #tpe-dl:hover, #tpe-pdf:hover, #isn-dl:hover, #isn-pdf:hover
{
  transform: scale(1.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
 
 
#ppp, #tpe, #isn
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid 3px black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
 
#ppp
{
    background-image: url("/images/ppp.jpg");
}
#tpe
{
    background-image: url("/images/tpe.jpg");
}
#isn
{
    background-image: url("/images/isn.jpeg");
}
 
.ppp-bouttons, .isn-bouttons, .tpe-bouttons
{
 
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-basis: 48%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
 
#ppp-dl, #tpe-dl, #isn-dl, #ppp-pdf, #tpe-pdf, #isn-pdf
{
    background-position: center;
    border: solid 3px black;
    background-size: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 47%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #292929cc;
 
}
 
#ppp-dl, #tpe-dl, #isn-dl
{
    background-image: url("/images/dl-claire.png");
}
 
#ppp-pdf, #tpe-pdf, #isn-pdf
{
    background-image: url("/images/pdf-claire.png");
}
 
p
{
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #bababa;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
 
.div-text
{
    border-bottom: solid 3px black;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    background-color: #2929299e;
    height:70px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
     
}
```

```html
<div class="projetsdiv">
     
    <div class="ppp">
        <div id="ppp">
            <div class="div-text">
                 <p> MON PPP </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ppp-bouttons">
             
            <div id="ppp-dl" onclick="window.open('#','PPP');"></div>
            <div id="ppp-pdf" onclick="window.open('#','PDF PPP');"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
     
     
    <div class="tpe">
        <div id="tpe">
            <div class="div-text">
                 <p> MON TPE </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tpe-bouttons">
            <div id="tpe-dl" onclick="window.open('#','TPE');"></div>
            <div id="tpe-pdf" onclick="window.open('#','PDF TPE');"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
         
    <div class="isn">
        <div id="isn">
            <div class="div-text">
                 <p> MON ISN </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="isn-bouttons">
            <div id="isn-dl" onclick="window.open('#','ISN');"></div>
            <div id="isn-pdf" onclick="window.open('#','PDF ISN');"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
 
</div>
```

I manage to partially get what I want with this code:

```
.projetsdiv:hover > *:not(*:hover)
{
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Or this code which blurs the divs but only the ones below:

```
.projetsdiv > *:hover ~ *:not(*:hover)
{
    filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new class **.blur** to each of the three divs

```
<div class="ppp blur">
   ...
</div>
<div class="tpe blur">
   ...
</div>
<div class="isn blur">
   ...
</div>
```

Then you can make the changes with jquery

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.blur').mouseenter(function(){
  $('.blur').css('filter','blur(5px)'); // Blurs each .blur div
  $(this).css('filter','blur(0px)');    // Removes blur from the currently hovered .blur div
})
$('.blur').mouseleave(function(){
  $('.blur').css('filter','blur(0px)'); // Removes blur from all when none are hovered
})
</script>
```

[Here is a pen with these changes in place](https://codepen.io/cawoelk/pen/XWJRbvJ?editors=1100)

Answer (score 1):

How about keeping them blurred initially, and removing blur on hover?

```css
.projetsdiv
{
    height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    align-items: center;
}
 
.isn, .tpe, .ppp
{
    width: 25%;
    align-items: center;
}
 
.isn:hover, .tpe:hover, .ppp:hover
{
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
 
#ppp-dl, #ppp-pdf, #tpe-dl, #tpe-pdf, #isn-dl, #isn-pdf{
  filter: blur(5px);
}
#ppp-dl:hover, #ppp-pdf:hover, #tpe-dl:hover, #tpe-pdf:hover, #isn-dl:hover, #isn-pdf:hover
{
  transform: scale(1.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: blur(0px);
}
 
 
#ppp, #tpe, #isn
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid 3px black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
 
#ppp
{
    background-image: url("/images/ppp.jpg");
}
#tpe
{
    background-image: url("/images/tpe.jpg");
}
#isn
{
    background-image: url("/images/isn.jpeg");
}
 
.ppp-bouttons, .isn-bouttons, .tpe-bouttons
{
 
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-basis: 48%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
 
#ppp-dl, #tpe-dl, #isn-dl, #ppp-pdf, #tpe-pdf, #isn-pdf
{
    background-position: center;
    border: solid 3px black;
    background-size: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 47%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #292929cc;
 
}
 
#ppp-dl, #tpe-dl, #isn-dl
{
    background-image: url("/images/dl-claire.png");
}
 
#ppp-pdf, #tpe-pdf, #isn-pdf
{
    background-image: url("/images/pdf-claire.png");
}
 
p
{
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #bababa;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
 
.div-text
{
    border-bottom: solid 3px black;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    background-color: #2929299e;
    height:70px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
     
}
```

```html
<div class="projetsdiv">
     
    <div class="ppp">
        <div id="ppp">
            <div class="div-text">
                 <p> MON PPP </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ppp-bouttons">
             
            <div id="ppp-dl" onclick="window.open('#','PPP');"></div>
            <div id="ppp-pdf" onclick="window.open('#','PDF PPP');"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
     
     
    <div class="tpe">
        <div id="tpe">
            <div class="div-text">
                 <p> MON TPE </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tpe-bouttons">
            <div id="tpe-dl" onclick="window.open('#','TPE');"></div>
            <div id="tpe-pdf" onclick="window.open('#','PDF TPE');"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
         
    <div class="isn">
        <div id="isn">
            <div class="div-text">
                 <p> MON ISN </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="isn-bouttons">
            <div id="isn-dl" onclick="window.open('#','ISN');"></div>
            <div id="isn-pdf" onclick="window.open('#','PDF ISN');"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but i don't want all div blured initaly

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can use this bit of code:

```
.projetsdiv:hover > div:not(:hover) {
  filter: blur(5px)
}
```

but it's not ideal - it will behave strangely if you add more elements to your project, so generally instead of doing it on the main parent element, you should do it only on the container element for the elements you want affected by blur.

See it in action here:

```css
.projetsdiv {
  height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  align-items: center;
}

.isn,
.tpe,
.ppp {
  width: 25%;
  align-items: center;
}

.isn:hover,
.tpe:hover,
.ppp:hover {
  transform: scale(1.25);
}

#ppp-dl:hover,
#ppp-pdf:hover,
#tpe-dl:hover,
#tpe-pdf:hover,
#isn-dl:hover,
#isn-pdf:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#ppp,
#tpe,
#isn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 3px black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#ppp {
  background-image: url("/images/ppp.jpg");
}

#tpe {
  background-image: url("/images/tpe.jpg");
}

#isn {
  background-image: url("/images/isn.jpeg");
}

.ppp-bouttons,
.isn-bouttons,
.tpe-bouttons {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-basis: 48%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#ppp-dl,
#tpe-dl,
#isn-dl,
#ppp-pdf,
#tpe-pdf,
#isn-pdf {
  background-position: center;
  border: solid 3px black;
  background-size: 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 47%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #292929cc;
}

#ppp-dl,
#tpe-dl,
#isn-dl {
  background-image: url("/images/dl-claire.png");
}

#ppp-pdf,
#tpe-pdf,
#isn-pdf {
  background-image: url("/images/pdf-claire.png");
}

p {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #bababa;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.div-text {
  border-bottom: solid 3px black;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  background-color: #2929299e;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.projetsdiv:hover > div:not(:hover) {
  filter: blur(5px)
}
```

```html
<div class="projetsdiv">

  <div class="ppp">
    <div id="ppp">
      <div class="div-text">
        <p> MON PPP </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ppp-bouttons">

      <div id="ppp-dl" onclick="window.open('#','PPP');"></div>
      <div id="ppp-pdf" onclick="window.open('#','PDF PPP');"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="tpe">
    <div id="tpe">
      <div class="div-text">
        <p> MON TPE </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tpe-bouttons">
      <div id="tpe-dl" onclick="window.open('#','TPE');"></div>
      <div id="tpe-pdf" onclick="window.open('#','PDF TPE');"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="isn">
    <div id="isn">
      <div class="div-text">
        <p> MON ISN </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="isn-bouttons">
      <div id="isn-dl" onclick="window.open('#','ISN');"></div>
      <div id="isn-pdf" onclick="window.open('#','PDF ISN');"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```